# Integrity constraint error referring to quote_item table while adding product to cart

Tags: magento2, database, addtocart, quote, magento2.2.3

I am getting the following error while trying to add product to cart in Magento 2.2.3.

> [2018-05-02 09:52:43] report.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`magento2`.`quote_item`, CONSTRAINT
>   `QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`)
>   REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT
>   INTO `quote_item` (`product_id`, `store_id`, `is_virtual`, `sku`,
>   `name`, `is_qty_decimal`, `weight`, `qty`, `product_type`,
>   `base_cost`, `subscription_frequency`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?) {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code:
>   23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot
>   add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`magento2`.`quote_item`, CONSTRAINT
>   `QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`)
>   REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT
>   INTO `quote_item` (`product_id`, `store_id`, `is_virtual`, `sku`,
>   `name`, `is_qty_decimal`, `weight`, `qty`, `product_type`,
>   `base_cost`, `subscription_frequency`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?) at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:235,
>   PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`magento2`.`quote_item`, CONSTRAINT
>   `QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`)
>   REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228)"}
>   []

I have added a custom column in *quote_item* table. Not sure if this is the issue. Kindly help resolve it. TIA

**EDIT:**

I'm updating my custom using event - **checkout_cart_product_add_after** . Below is my observer update code.

```
<?php

namespace Addon\Recur\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    protected $_layout;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_request;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     )
    {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
    }


    /**
     * Add order information into GA block to render on checkout success pages
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        /* @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $post = $this->_request->getParam('frequency');
        $item->setSubscriptionFrequency($post);
        $item->save();

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');  
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();  
        $logger->addWriter($writer);  
        $logger->info($post);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem when i tried to change data on quote items with the **checkout_cart_product_add_after** event. This event is fired after every product add, but before the cart is saved. Check the `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add` line 108-113 for reference. So if you want to save the quote item on a new session there is no quote yet and there is no quote_id to reference to.

In my case, i just left the `$item->save();` out, because it will be saved afterwards automatically.